# Constructor and Unit Testing

Tags: scala, class, unit-testing

I have a class `XmlRecord`. This class will deal with reading/writing to an xml file. At the moment, I have the following for that class:

```
class XmlRecord {
   private val _file = new File("file.xml")
}
```

I want this class to somehow create the file if it doesn't exist. I know how to achieve this but I'm unsure how to design it in an Object Orientated way. I think I have two options:

1. Do I add a code to the constructor (or a call to a private method) that will create this file automatically if it doesn't exist. My problem with this method is that how do I unit test this as this code is effectively private code? Would I have to inject the File dependency so it could be mocked during testing?
2. Do I get the constructor to return an exception or implement a public method for the class so that the caller can use it to check if a file needs to be created? If so, the caller would then call another public method that would create the file. Again I think I would need to inject the dependency.

I hope that makes sense. I'm just trying to get a better grasp on designing my classes.

Comment: Not sure the ctor is the best place to do that

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> The presence of abstractions to accomplish DIP have other design
> implications in an Object Oriented program:
>
> All member variables in a class must be interfaces or abstracts.
> All concrete class packages must connect only through interface/abstract classes packages.
> No class should derive from a concrete class.
> No method should override an implemented method.[5]
> All variable instantiation requires the implementation of a Creational pattern as the Factory Method or the Factory pattern, or the more complex use of a Dependency Injection framework.
> ```

[Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)